# Sql Case statement with value of 2+ columns greater than 1

Tags: sql, addition, case-statement

I need to add the values in a row from three columns. When the value is greater than 1, it needs to populate a specific phrase.

So ... example

```
From temp_table_tx = count_of_x    
From temp_table_ty = count_of_y    
From temp_table_tz = count_of_z
```

I currently have the following, which only gives me an error.

```
CASE 
    WHEN (tx.count_of_x + ty.count_of_y + tz.count_of_z) >1 THEN 'Exception_present'
    WHEN (tx.count_of_x + ty.count_of_y + tz.count_of_z) <1 THEN  'No_Exceptions'
ELSE 'error'
End As exceptions
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your query (and perhaps sample data and expected results), it's hard to know what's going on.  At a glance, that `case` statement looks ok to me.

Comment: Just a thought, when you say it gives you an `error`, do you mean that's the result of the `case` statement?  Or your query is not running and returning an error?  If it runs and you are receiving `error` as the result, perhaps one of the counts is `null` thus not matching either `when` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You would get `'error'` if any counts were `NULL`.  So, this might fix your problem:

```
(CASE WHEN coalesce(tx.count_of_x, 0) + coalesce(ty.count_of_y, 0) + coalesce(tz.count_of_z, 0) > 1
      THEN 'Exception_present'
      WHEN coalesce(tx.count_of_x, 0) + coalesce(ty.count_of_y, 0) + coalesce(tz.count_of_z, 0) < 1 THEN 'No_Exceptions'
      ELSE 'error'
 END) As exceptions
```

It seems odd, though, that a count of exactly "1" would be considered an error.